# PROFINET polling over ethernet

Tags: .net, polling, industrial

Does anyone have experience in work with PROFINET protocol ? I wounder about using PROFINET implementing devices and polling these devices over ethernet.

I would like to make .NET program that acquire data from some industrial devices like PLC implementing PROFINET protocol.

Is it possible to do polling data (from PLC for instance) at high speed (more then standard ethernet 100 Mb/s). I wounder if it's possible over PROFINET protocol and what requirements do I have to meet to perform such fast polling.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is slightly off-topic, I'd suggest to have a look at tother sites in the SE-Network, such as http://superuser.com/ or http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "Is it possible to do polling data (from PLC for instance) at high speed (more then standard ethernet 100 Mb/s)" How does that make sense if the device itself is attached via a 100Mb/s link (that's what PROFINET supports IIRC).

Answer (score 0):

Certainly communication from .NET is possible, since PROFINET is running on top of Ethernet protocol, so as long as you can send Ethernet frames, you can basically communicate over PROFINET.

The question however is - what data do you want to acquire? MAC address? IP Address? PROFINET Records? This will highly influence the complexity of your application, and at this place no simple answer exists.

Regarding last part of your question, communicating with any PROFINET device on speed different than 100Mbps is not possible, since PROFINET enforces 100Mbps speed of Ethernet.